# htaccess root point to subdirectory without showing folder path

Tags: .htaccess

I've tried all sorts of ways. I am having trouble redirecting the root `.htaccess` file to a `subdirectory/public` file.
Currently, the root redirects to the folder but the path of file shows up in the url.

For example:
`website.com/flarum/public` should be `website.com`

```
... 
public_html   
-- .htaccess // below
-- flarum
---- public
------.htaccess //default flarum's htaccess
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /flarum/public/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/flarum/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /flarum/public/$1
```

right now it is showing, `website.com/flarum/public` where it should be `website.com`

Comment: This should not be handled with htaccess ..  Change the default directory in your Vhosts file from `/var/www/website/public_html` to `/var/www/website/public_html/flarum/public` -- This can be found in a `conf` file inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory -- Restart Apache after changing this directive

Comment: Please also include the contents of the `/flarum/public/.htaccess` file in your question. There's nothing in what you've posted (ie. the root `.htaccess` file) that would cause the file-path to be exposed, unless the folder is actually in the URL path?

Comment: @Zak That's fair enough if you have access to the server config, but many don't. And if you have access to the server config there's probably other things you would do differently as well (there is also a 2nd `.htaccess` in play here). Another alternative is to simply move the contents of the `/flarum/public` directory to the document root. (Any other files above this are then moved above the document root. But again, this depends on the server config.)